# How do we call a class function that takes an input prompt and processes said input?

Tags: python

(REVISED)Here is an MRE of my problem:

```
class TradeUp():
    def __init__(self):
        self.num1, self.num2 = self.prompt_user()
        self.total = self.add()

    def prompt_user(self):
        # ask the user to input custom values
        num1 = int(input('enter a number'))
        num2 = int(input('enter another'))
        return num1, num2

    def add(self):
        total = self.num1 + self.num2
        return total

    def main(self):
        print(self.total)

TradeUp().main()
```

The main objective in this program is to get the user's input and processing it from only one method(Tradeup.main), which in turn calls the methods "prompt_user" and "add", and finally printing the processed total value. What do I need to change so my program would be cleaner and expandable for multiple variables?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Thnk about the order in which things are happening, what's being returned at each point, and what's being assigned to. Walk through the code manually and draw out what's happening at each statement.

Comment: @Prune This is the most basic minimal, reproducible example I can think of, sadly.

Comment: You didn't trace the intermediate operation.  However, that seems to be more of a solution than a posting gripe.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a few `print` statements to trace your code.
Your single line of non-class code invokes the class constructor.  This calls `prompt_user` twice.  When that's done, your `main` method calls it a third time.